# Comparing $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$ without calculating them

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation, pi

How can I

> compare (without calculator or similar device) the values of $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$ ?

Comment: More generally: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Another proof uses the fact that $\displaystyle \pi \ne e$ and that [$e^x > 1 + x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex) for $x \ne 0$.

We have $$e^{\pi/e -1} > \pi/e,$$

and so

$$e^{\pi/e} > \pi.$$

Thus,

$$e^{\pi} > \pi^e.$$

**Note**: This proof is not specific to $\pi$.

Comment: This is from [The Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erdős#Personality)! Impeccable proof.

Comment: if x is negative than would your first equation which is e^x > 1 + x be true ?

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia: Yes, it is true. Consider $f(x) = e^x -1 -x$. It's derivative is $e^x -1$ which is $\lt 0$ for $x \lt 0$ and $\gt 0$ for $x \gt 0$, so $f$ decreases from $-\infty$ to $0$, and increases from $0$ to $\infty$. Since $f(0) = 0$...

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that this works for all positive numbers which aren't $e$. The proof has nothing to do with $\pi$.

Comment: @NikolajK: Thank you for the suggestion! Done.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get $e^{π/e−1}>π/e$?

Comment: @MrAP: $ x = \frac{\pi}{e} -1$. Now use $e^x \gt x + 1$.

Comment: How did you get the intuition to make the substitution $x = \frac{\pi}{e} - 1$? I understand how to get to the step $e^x > 1 + x$, but I wouldn't have thought of the substitution for $x$ so quickly. Is there some kind of obvious procedure you followed?

Comment: @David: Sorry to be of no help :(. No idea what the thought process was, it has been quite a while.

Answer (score 50):

This is an old chestnut. As a hint, it's easier to consider the more
general problem: for which positive $x$ is $e^x>x^e$?

Comment: one more step, why not considering y^x and x^y

Answer (score 45):

Alternatively, we can compare $e^{1/e}$ and $\pi^{1/\pi}$.

Let $f(x) = x^{1/x}$. Then $f'(x) = x^{1/x} (1 - \log(x))/x^2$. Since $\log(x) > 1$ for $x > e$, we see that $f'(x) < 0$ for $e < x < \pi$. We conclude that $\pi^{1/\pi} < e^{1/e}$, and so $\pi^e < e^\pi$.

The same calculation shows that $f(x)$ reaches its maximum at $e^{1/e}$, and so in general $x^e < e^x$.

Comment: Correction: $\text{log}(x)<1$ for $x<e$.

Comment: Your argument appears to need $x>e$, but it is easy to also include $x<e$ as well i the $x^e<e^x$ inequality.

Comment: It doesn't really need $\log x > 1$. All you need is that the only solution of $\log x = 1$ is $x = e$.

Answer (score 45):

From *[Proofs without Words](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Kx2cjyzTIYkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=proofs+without+words&hl=en&ei=7RnYTLrRHZnc4wbR-on9Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.

[image]

Comment: Which software did you use to plot this figure?

Answer (score 19):

Let $f (x) =$ $x^\frac1x$

Find value of $x$ such that function  gets maximum value

For this functions for $x=e$ function will get the maximum value

so $e^\frac1e$ is greater than $\pi^\frac1\pi$

so $e^\pi$ is greater than $\pi ^e$.

Answer (score 15):

Elaborating Robin's answer take $f(x) = \log{x} - \frac{x}{e}$.  We have $$f'(x)= \frac{e-x}{xe}$$ Thus $f'(x)>0$ for $0 < x < e$ and $f'(x) <0$ if $x > e$. Consequently, we have $f(x) < f(e)$ if $x \neq e$.

**Exercise:** Try to prove this using the same methods: $2^{\sqrt{2}} < e$.

Answer (score 10):

Hint:

Prove that the function $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x^e}, x\geq e$ is strictly increasing on the interval $x\in \left [ e,\pi \right ]$. What is $f(e)$ and $f(\pi)$?

Answer (score 8):

Another visual proof. Recently published in arXiv[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yet another line of thought would be this:
$$\begin{align}
e^{\pi} > \pi^e &\iff \pi \ln(e)>e\ln(\pi)\\
&\iff \pi >e\ln(\pi) \\
&\iff \ln(\pi)>\ln(e)+\ln (\ln (\pi)) \\
&\iff \ln(\pi)>1+\ln (\ln (\pi))
\end{align}$$
By concavity of $\ln$, $x-1>\ln(x)$ for all $x\neq 1$. With $x=\ln(\pi)$ we get the inequality wanted.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
&e^\pi>\pi^e \\[5pt]
\iff&\exp(\pi)>\exp(e\log\pi) \\[5pt]
\iff&\pi>e\log\pi \\[5pt]
\iff&\frac{\pi}{\log\pi}>e \\[5pt]
\iff&\frac{\pi}{\log\pi}>\frac{e}{\log e}
\end{align}
The final line is true because the function $\dfrac{x}{\log x}$ is strictly increasing on $[e,\infty) \, ,$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $n = e^\pi$, $m = \pi^e$ and $s = \log \pi$. Then $\log n = \pi = e^s$ and $\log m = e \log \pi = es$. Then $$\log \frac {n} {m} = \log n - \log m = e (e^{s - 1} - s).$$ By Taylor expansion, we have $$e^{s - 1} = 1 + (s - 1) + \cdots > s.$$ Then $$\log \frac {n} {m} = e (e^{s - 1} - s) > 0.$$ Hence, $n > m$.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a recent one. Another visual proof. I am doubtful if it has open access.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-019-09964-x

Answer (score 1):

Not that this question needs another answer, but here is a proof of $e^\pi > \pi^e$ using the Mean Value Theorem applied to $\ln x$ on the interval $(e,\pi)$, along with the assumptions that $e<\pi$, $\ln$ is increasing, and $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = \frac{1}{x}$.

By the MVT, there exists $c \in (e,\pi)$ such that
$$ \frac{\ln \pi - \ln e}{\pi - e} = \frac{1}{c} $$
We can increase the right hand side by replacing $c$ with the smaller number $e$, and so we have
$$ \frac{\ln \pi - \ln e}{\pi - e} < \frac{1}{e} $$
and thus
$$ {\ln \pi - \ln e} < \frac{1}{e}(\pi-e) $$
or
$$ {\ln \pi - 1} < \frac{\pi}{e}-1 $$
which gives
$$ e \ln \pi < \pi \ln e$$
and therefore
$$ e^\pi < \pi^e$$

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$f(x) = e^x$$

$$G(x) = x^e$$

We can simply show that

$$f(e)=G(e)$$

$$f'(e)=G'(e)$$

For $x > e$ the $f(x)$ will grow faster than $G(x)$

Then

$$e^{\pi} > \pi^{e}$$

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is true that $e^x > x^e$ for all $x > e.$
Here's a proof using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Note that $e^{x-2} > x^{e-2}$ for all $x > e.$ This can be easily verified by noting that one of these is convex and the other is concave and they are equal at $x=e$ and evaluating the derivatives at this point.

Then, $e^{x-1} - (e-1) x^{e-2} \geq e(e^{x-2} - x^{e-2}) > 0$ for $x > e.$

But then let $g(x) = e^{x-1} - x^{e-1}$ and noting that $g'(x) = e^{x-1} - (e-1) x^{e-2} > 0$ we thus have for all $x > e,$
$$g(x) - g(e) = g(x) = \int_{e}^{x} [ e^{x-1} - (e-1) x^{e-2} ] dx > 0 $$

And then letting $f(x) = e^x - x^e$ we have $f'(x) = e^x - e x^{e-1} = e g(x) > 0$

And by similar argument conclude that $$f(x) - f(e) = f(x) = \int_{e}^{x} e g(x) dx > 0$$ for all $x \geq e.$