# Prove that $e ^ π$ > $π ^ e$.

Tags: logarithms, polylogarithm

Prove that: $$e ^ π > π ^ e.$$
**Hint:** Take the natural log of both sides and try to define a suitable function that has the essential properties that yields the above inequality

Comment: $f(x)=x^{-1}\log x$, optimize you must.

Comment: One of those questions that gets asked many, many times:  see, for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi  @PedroTamaroff Optimization at the foot of Master Yoda learn you did?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337565/a-question-comparing-pie-to-e-pi

Comment: duplicate questions on the prowl

Comment: I love this link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.03163.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $f(x) = \frac{ \ln x }{x} $. then $f' = \frac{1 - \ln x}{x^2} $. $f'  = 0 \iff 1 - \ln x = 0 \iff x = e $. Hence $\sup_x f(x) = f(e) = \frac{ \ln e }{e} $. In particular, this must be $> \frac{ \ln \pi}{ \pi} $.

$$ \therefore \frac{\ln e}{e} > \frac{ \ln \pi}{\pi} \iff e^\pi > \pi^e$$

Answer (score 0):

**Another Hint:**
$$
x^y > y^x \iff y \log x > x \log y \iff \frac{\log y}{y} < \frac{\log x}{x}.
$$

Comment: Sorry but one can't see, only by looking at it without graph, that $\frac {ln(e)}{e}>\frac{ln(\pi)}{\pi}$ the difference is really small

Comment: @Ale You don't just look at it, you need to use the first hint you had.  Which is, find a function.  My hint is intended to make it clear that the desired function is $f(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}$.