# Prove that ${e\over {\pi}}\lt{\sqrt3\over{2}}$ without using a calculator.

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, irrational-numbers, pi, number-comparison

I have been working on a known question for a long time (this is "Proving that $e^{\pi}-{\pi}^e\lt 1$ without using a calculator") during this time I realized the ${e\over {\pi}}\lt{\sqrt3\over{2}}$.
I have no solution so far. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A question comparing $\pi^e$ to $e^\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337565/a-question-comparing-pie-to-e-pi)

Comment: With "prove" you mean a method not involving calculating $e$, $\pi$ or other constants by hand, right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$ without calculating them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi-without-calculating-them)

Comment: Please read the question, it's not a duplicate

Comment: Peter, yes. Same as you can see on the following link . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410230/proving-that-e-pi-pie-lt-1-without-using-a-calculator

Comment: this will be tricky, as it's a close inequality.  $pi/e \approx 0.865256$ while $\sqrt{3}/2 \approx 0.866205$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Calculation without any computer, only with patience.* :-D

$\displaystyle e<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\enspace$ is equivalent to $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{2}{9}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} =\frac{2e^2}{9}<\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2)$

Case $\,(A)\,$ :

We have $\enspace\displaystyle \prod\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{k+9}{4}>1\enspace$ for all $\,n\geq 0\,$ and therefore $\,4^{n+1}8!<(n+9)!\,$ .

It follows $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{2^{n+1}8!}{(n+9)!}<\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\enspace$ and with the summation over $\,n=0,1,2,…\,$ we get

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n+1}8!}{(n+9)!}< \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=1\enspace$ which leads to $\enspace\displaystyle e^2 = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} < \sum\limits_{n=0}^7 \frac{2^n}{n!} + \frac{2^9}{8!} \,$ .

Case $\,(B)\,$ :

The Euler–Maclaurin formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) gives us a good approximation for $\,\zeta(2)\,$ and we get

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^4  \frac{1}{n^2}  + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{50} + \frac{1}{6\cdot 125} - \frac{1}{30\cdot 5^5}<\zeta(2)\,$ .

Cases $\,(A)\,$ and $\,(B)\,$ together :

Now we have to prove the middle part of the following inequality.

$\displaystyle \frac{2e^2}{9} = \frac{2}{9}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} < \frac{2}{9}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^7 \frac{2^n}{n!} + \frac{2^9}{8!}\right)<$

$\displaystyle <\sum\limits_{n=0}^4  \frac{1}{n^2}  + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{50} + \frac{1}{6\cdot 125} - \frac{1}{30\cdot 5^5}<\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\,$

or simply $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{2e^2}{9} < \frac{4658}{2835} < \frac{3701101}{2250000} < \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

And with $\,4658\cdot 2250000 =10480500000 < 10492621335=2835\cdot 3701101$

the claim is proofed.

Comment: Some great ideas here...

Comment: @orangeskid : Thanks ... :-)

Comment: I am sorry for the late congratulation. Your solution should be taught. Thanks for it.

Comment: @JV.Stalker : You are welcome. It was a pleasure. :-)