# Why Is $\ln 23+\cfrac{1}{\color{red}{163}+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{\color{red}{41}}}}\approx\pi$

Tags: number-theory, approximation, pi, continued-fractions

I know from reading that the [Heegner number 163](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) yields the prime generating or [Euler Lucky Number 41](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_numbers_of_Euler). Now apparently [$\ln23<\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482193/help-me-prove-pie23e-pi) and this can be shown without calculators. I noticed that
$$ 
\pi-\ln23= \cfrac{1}{\color{red}{163}
          + \cfrac{1}{1
          + \cfrac{1}{\color{red}{41} + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cdots}}}}
$$

> **Question:** *Are there any "good" mathematical reasons why the largest Heegner and largest Euler Lucky number occur within the first three (-four ?)
>   terms  of the expansion*? Or is it purely coincidence ?

---

Indeed the finite c.f. $$\cfrac{1}{\color{red}{163}
          + \cfrac{1}{1
          + \cfrac{1}{\color{red}{41}}}}:=\frac{42}{6887}\approx 0.00609843\ldots.$$  In turn this yields the crude approximation $$\ln 23+\frac{42}{6887}\approx\pi;$$ which I believe gives the first 8 digits of $\pi$ correctly.

Comment: TIL about \cfrac. Neat!

Comment: Maybe use \ln for the Natural logarithm? Or at least make clear what base you are using.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I see your point. I will edit to make that clear.