# How Do I show that $\sqrt{2\pi}<\Phi^{-1}\left( \frac{23}{\exp(\pi)}\right)$ without calculators?

Tags: self-learning, normal-distribution

> **Question:** How might I show without calculators that
> $$ 
> \sqrt{2\pi}<\Phi^{-1}\left( \frac{23}{\exp(\pi)}\right); \label{a}\tag{1}
> $$
> where
> $\Phi^{-1}()$ is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function
> of the standard normal distribution, sometimes called the probit function.

---

Indeed numerical calculations show that
$$ 
\color{blue}{2.506628274631\ldots}=\sqrt{2\pi}<\Phi^{-1}\left( \frac{23}{\exp(\pi)}\right)=\color{blue}{2.50747379179\ldots} 
$$
So $\ref{a}$ is justified numerically. But attempting to show it is true without resorting to calculators has proven difficult. Of course
$
\Phi\sqrt{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+\text{Erf}\sqrt{2\pi}\bigg)
$
and so we might want to show that
$
\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+\text{Erf}\sqrt{2\pi}\bigg)>\frac{23}{\exp(\pi)}
$
is false drawing the contradiction and so establishing the inequality in $\ref{a}.$ In particular we might leverage our [knowledge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482193/help-me-prove-pie23e-pi) that $\ln23<\pi$ and so $23<\exp(\pi)$, all of which can be shown without calculators. But this route has proven illusive. I also tried reasoning about $\ref{a}$ geometrically by looking at the summated volume of unit balls over $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

I should mention that I am a new learner to math and statistics and probability. Just to be pedantic all calculation can be found [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282pi%29%3Cprobit%2823%2Fexp%28pi%29%29) on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: This begs an awful lot of questions about how you know various things (e.g., that $\ln 23 < \pi$) without using a "calculator".

Comment: Wow that's a tiny difference. Why do you want to do this?