# Comparing $\gamma^e$ and $e^\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, inequality

How can I calculate without calculator or something like this

**the values of $\gamma^e$ and $e^\gamma$**

in order to compare them?

($\gamma$ the Euler-Mascheroni constant)

---

Note: the shape of this question lend from the beautiful question of [Mirzodaler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2779/mirzodaler) >>> [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi).

Comment: Have you read the solutions on the page you mention? Because if you did, you should realize that the solution is already mentioned.

Comment: The Mascheroni constant? may you help how and where?

Comment: Some of the tricks mentioned don't depend on it being the Mascheroni constant or the Avogadro number or whatever.

Comment: Got it! Robin Chapman! I think we wrote in parallel perhaps.

Comment: The question about $\pi$ is not immediate because both $e$ and $\pi$ are relatively close to $3$. Here, since $\gamma\approx 0.5$ it is obvious that one is larger than $1$ whereas the other is clearly not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$γ^e=e^{e\lnγ}$$
So,the problem is comparing $γ$ and $e\lnγ$,
as well as,the sign of $γ-e\lnγ$.
Consider the function $$f(x)=x-e\ln x$$ and its monotony.