# Which one is bigger? $e^{\pi} $ or $\pi^e$

Tags: calculus

$e^{\pi}$ or  $\pi^e$,
Can we find which one is bigger by using calculus?

Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi

Comment: I did not know that it is already asked.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @messel, a little googling before asking a question should help.  I would like to know about efficient searching in mSE

Comment: actually,I did not search in google, but when writing question, the site shows similar words,in there it has not been seen because we use diffrent words to ask same question. And in general,typing math question in google is diffucult.

Comment: @messel, https://www.google.co.in/#q=which+is+bigger+pi%5Ee+or+e%5Epi

Comment: Of course,it is generally diffucult :) Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$e^\pi>\pi^e\iff\pi>e\log\pi\iff\frac{\log e}e=\frac1e>\frac{\log\pi}\pi$$

Now look at the function

$$f(x):=\frac{\log x}x\;,\;\;x\ge e\implies f'(x)=\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}\le0\implies f(x)$$

is monotone descending, and thus

$$e<\pi\implies \frac1e=\frac{\log e}e=f(e)>f(\pi)=\frac{\log\pi}\pi$$

Comment: So brief and beautiful!