# Comparing $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$

Tags: calculus, soft-question, problem-solving

[Comparing $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$ without calculating them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi)

I read the answer there but I didn't understand one thing. How I should know to put $\dfrac{π}e-1$ instead of $x$? If I had this question on a test, I had no idea what to put instead of $x$. I mean, why the first thing I need to think about is to calculte when $x=\dfrac{π}e-11$ .

I hope you understand my question.

**Note :**

This is not a duplicate - I'm not asking what is bigger - I don't understand the answer, that's all!

Comment: This is what is called a "happy idea". Sometimes the step between the known ($e^x \geq x+1$) and the unknown ($e^\pi > \pi^e$) is not obvious but some techniques exist that can help. I suggest you read "How to solve it" by G.Pólya for some of those techniques.

Comment: Huh, I had always maximized the function $x^{e\pi \over x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Your question is less about whether you understand the proof, and more about how you would construct such a proof.

In a test, you wouldn't be expected to find that argument, which is a slick simple argument that was found by somebody probably with a little extra time, trying to find a proof without using general properties about derivatives.

The usual argument is the [answer given by Yuval Filmus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7914/7933).