# How to prove which of two numbers written as powers is bigger?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Prove which number is larger:

a) $10^{100!}$ or $10^{10^{100}}$

b) $e^\pi$ or $\pi^e$

I know we all know how to plug these into the calculator and check, but how someone mathematically prove which one is bigger with words and calculations?

Comment: I think there's already a question on MSE that deals with $b)$.

Comment: Have you tried plugging $10^{10^{100}}$ into your calculator?

Comment: Yes but my calculator wouldnt be proving it exactly, because I wouldn't know exactly what's going on it would just be spitting out an answer, if that makes any sense.

Comment: For b, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892. For a: is $10^{100}$ larger than 100?

Comment: @TonyK There is a calculator that can handle and compare numbers like this: http://mrob.com/pub/perl/hypercalc.html

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov You really don't need a calculator for problems such as these...

Comment: Sorry I forgot the ! after the 100 in part a

Comment: @MorrisB-- Yeah... the $!$ makes a bit of a difference, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (a), it boils to comparing $1$ and
$$
\frac{100!}{10^{100}}=\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{10}\cdot\cdots\frac{100}{10}.\tag{*}
$$
Only the fractions $\frac{1}{10},\ldots,\frac{9}{10}$ are less than $1$ but they are more than compensated for by $\frac{100}{10},\frac{90}{10},\ldots,\frac{20}{10}$. Other fractions are greater or equal to $1$. So it should be clear that the expression in (*) is greater than $1$. This of course means $10^{100!}>10^{10^{100}}$.

For (b), an answer is already linked to in the comment or you can look at Edward Jiang's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953369/136641).

Answer (score 1):

For $a)$, you are comparing 
$$
10^{100} \text{ and } 10^{10^{100}} 
$$
Realize that:
$$
10^{10^{100}} = 10^{({10^{2}})^{50}}=(10^{100^{50}}) =10^{100\cdot 100\cdot100\cdot\ldots\cdot 100}=((10^{100})^{100})^{100} )^{100}\ldots)^{100} 
$$
Use the fact that for the function $f(x) = x^{100}$, $f(x) > x$ for all $x > 1$. 
This can be easily seen as let:
$$
g(x) = f(x) - x
$$
Then $$
g'(x) = 100x^{99} -1 >0
$$
for all $x>1$
This gives $10^{100}>10$
$$(10^{100})^{100}>10^{100}\\ \vdots \\ ((10^{100})^{100})^{100} )^{100}\underbrace{\ldots}_{50})^{100} > ((10^{100})^{100})^{100} )^{100}\underbrace{\ldots}_{49})^{100} $$, etc. 
For b) see mrf's advice in the comments

Answer (score 0):

For (a) notice that $f(x) = 10^x$ is a strictly increasing function and $2<100 \Rightarrow 10^2<10^{100} \Rightarrow 10^{10^2} < 10^{10^{100}}$.

For (b) see in the comments.