# Which number is bigger?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Which number is bigger? $1.01^{101}$ or $2$? and how about $e^{\pi}$ or $\pi^e$?

Tried some algebraic manipulations to no end, so would love some suggestions or some different ways to approach those kind of problem

Comment: [it is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.01%5E%28101%29) $1.01^{101}=2.7318619677$

Comment: For first use [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Have you looked at all the similar questions on SE? The second part of your question has been answered on SE many times, for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi

Comment: @Surb yes, but wolfram isn't always by my side :)

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Thanks. bernoulli worked like a charm. I should've think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$A=1.01^{101}$$ So $$\log(A)=101\log(1.01)$$ Now use the very fast convergent expansion $$\log\Big(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\Big)=2\,\Big(\frac {x}{1}+\frac {x^3}{3}+\frac {x^5}{5}+\cdots\Big)$$ and make $\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac{101}{100}$ that is to say $x=\frac{1}{201}$. The first term (to which only positive terms will be added) is already  $$\log(A)=101\log(1.01)=2\times 101\times \frac{1}{201}=\frac{202}{201}>1$$ and then $A>e>2$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint for the first:** With $x = 0.01$ and $n = 101$, note that 
$$
(1 + x)^n = 1 + n\,x + \binom n2 x^2 + \cdots \geq 1 + n\,x
$$

**Hint for the second:**  It is equivalent to show that $e^{1/e} > \pi^{1/\pi}$.  In order to do so, consider the function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ and use calculus.

Answer (score 1):

$$x \to 0 , (1+x)^n \approx  1+nx \\(1.01)^101=(1+\frac{1}{100})^101 \approx  1+ 101(\frac{1}{100}) >2$$ for the second one 
Consider this function $$x^{\frac{1}{x}}$$. 
 $f'=x^{\frac{1}{x}}(\frac{1}{x^2})(1-\ln x)$,
    function has global maximum at $x=e$.

so $e^{\frac{1}{e}} \geq \pi^{\frac{1}{\pi}} \to $, and it is clear that the inequality is strict,$$(e^{\frac{1}{e}} \geq \pi^{\frac{1}{\pi}})^{e\pi} \to $$ so **$$e^{\pi}>\pi^{e}$$**

Comment: Similarity ($\sim$) say nothing about inequality. And $1.01^{100}\sim 2$ have not any sense. Or you meant $\approx$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we get $$e^{\pi}>\pi^{e}$$ use the function $$f(x)=\sqrt[x]{x}$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: aha i can only ask why not? this should be a hint, not a solution, see the "solution" above