# How can I prove without using a calculator that $\frac{1}{e} > \frac{\ln \pi}{\pi}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function, pi

Without using a calculator.

I can see that $\ln \pi$ is close to $1$ but a little bit greater...
Since $e$ is less than $\pi$, $\frac{1}{e}$ has to be a larger number.
I don't understand how someone could know $\ln \pi$ though without using a calculator?

I also then have to prove why $e^\pi > \pi^e$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi

Comment: @Surb: Sorry to ask this here. how could you find the related question to this? :) In most of the times I am unable to do so by searching!? Is there any other way or a special trick? :)

Comment: @H.R. No... I think searching methods have been extensively discussed in meta. But [that's](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24e%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%24+is+greater+than) what I did and then I looked at the source of the duplicate.

Comment: @Surb: Many Thanks, I thought that we can just search words not equations! :)

Comment: @H.R. Looking at the searching output, it seems that I found the question because of the "greater than" and not of the $e^{\pi}$...

Comment: @Surb: Take look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24e%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%24+)! :)

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ goes from $-\infty$ to $0$ and its only maximun is given  by $f(e)=\frac 1e$ (because $f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$) so $f$ is increasing on the interval $]0,e[$ and decreasing on $]e,\infty[$.

On the other hand $\frac{1}{e} > \frac{\ln \pi}{\pi}\iff \frac{\ln e}{e} > \frac{\ln \pi}{\pi}$ and since $e<\pi$ we finish because of the interval where $f$ is decreasing.