# How to prove that $\pi > e\ln(\pi)$?

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

How can you prove the following inequality?
$$\pi > e\ln(\pi)$$

**Edit:** I have tried the following, $\pi = e^{\ln(\pi)}$ so:
$$e^{\ln(\pi)} > e\ln(\pi)$$
$$e^{\ln(\pi)-1} > \ln(\pi)$$
$$\ln(\pi)-1>\ln(\ln(\pi))$$

I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Why write $e^{\ln \pi}$?  That's just $\pi$.

Comment: Hint:  It helps to write your inequality as $\frac 1e >\frac {\ln \pi}{\pi}$ and to note that $\frac 1e = \frac {\ln e}e$.  Think about $f(x)=\frac {\ln x}x$.

Comment: This is $e^\pi>\pi^e$, an old chestnut, which I am sure has been tackled here several times.

Comment: @Macavity Funny enough, searching MSE for `old chestnut` returns [Comparing $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$ without calculating them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi-without-calculating-them) as the second hit ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt[x] x$ is  a decreasing function for $x\ge e$ then since $\pi>e$

$$\large{\pi > e\ln \pi}$$
$$\large{\frac1e>\frac{\ln \pi}\pi}$$
$$\large{\frac1e > \ln(\pi^{\frac1\pi})}$$
Putting both as an exponent of $e$:
$$\large{e^{\frac1e}>\pi^\frac1\pi}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: define the function $$f(x)=x-e\ln(x)$$ for $$x>3$$ and use calculus,